# Preselect Printer and printer properties without bothering the user

Tags: python-3.x, printing, gtk3

I'm writing a Python3-Gtk3-application that prints QR-Labels on a label printer. Until now my code

```
...
psize = Gtk.PaperSize.new_custom('Our-QR-Label', 'QR-Label', 29, 42, Gtk.Unit.MM)
pagesetup = Gtk.PageSetup()
pagesetup.set_paper_size(psize)
...
pagesetup.set_orientation(Gtk.PageOrientation.PORTRAIT)

print_dialog = Gtk.PrintOperation()
print_dialog.set_n_pages(len(self.qrcodes))
print_dialog.set_default_page_setup(pagesetup)
print_dialog.connect("draw-page", self.print_page)
print_dialog.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG, None)
...
```

shows the printer dialog with the **default** printer selected. When the user selects the label printer and starts printing, anything works.

But since our users normally never see any printer dialogs, they will be confused and can mess up everything :-(

I know that I can call

```
print_dialog.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT, None)
```

to bypass the print dialog, but then the output goes to the standard printer, which is not the desired result.

So: How can I preset a printer (by name) to the Gtk.PrintOperation?

P.S.: I'm writing and testing my programs on Linux but our users work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of would be to save the print settings to a file. If the file doesn't exist, get the user to select a printer then save those settings to a file.

Retrieving print settings from file:

```
self.settings_file = ("my/settings/file")
try:
    settings = Gtk.PrintSettings.new_from_file(self.settings_file)
    print_dialog.set_print_settings(settings)
    #do your print stuff here without a dialog
except Exception as e:
    print ("Error when loading print settings file: ", str(e))
    settings = Gtk.PrintSettings()
    print_dialog.set_print_settings(settings)
    #do your print stuff here using a dialog
```

Capturing selected printer and saving to file:

```
result = print_dialog.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG, None)
if result == Gtk.PrintOperationResult.APPLY:
    settings = print_dialog.get_print_settings()
    settings.to_file(self.settings_file)
```